# High school geometry - rhombus, kite

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

[image]

I've solved the problems, do you think this is right?

1. Opposite sides are parallel, diagonals are perpendicular, and the length of the diagonals are equal so the type of quadrilateral that ABCD is a rhombus.

2-a. The axis of symmetry: EC,
gradient: 3-10/8-1=-1 so -1, and the equation is y=-x+11

2-b. The equation of BD: y=x-1
y=y, then -x+11=x-1
12=2x
6=x
substitute for x into equation: y=-6+11
y=5
Two diagonal EC and BD meet at (6,5)

3. I consider F=(2,9)
   FBCD is always a kite because:

- Diagonal line FC is the perpendicular bisector of BD (same as EC)
- The intersection of line FC and BD is the midpoint of BD (and also the same as the intersection of EC and BD)
- The distance between line FB and line FD are equal (7.07)
- The distance between line BC and CD are equal (5.10)
  This evidances show the FBCD is always a kite.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I don't think the diagonals of ABCD are equal. Show that AB=BC to prove that it's a rhombus or show that the diagonal bisect each other.

Comment: You showed that EC is the perpendicular bisector to BD. It follows that any point F on EC will be equidistant from B and D.